# How to write regex which returns only "I", followed by "J" or "V", and then between 1 and 3 numbers?

Tags: regex

Need to an expression that returns only things with an "I" followed by either a "J" or a "V" (No Quotes) and then a minimum of 1 number up to 3 numbers.

I J### 
I V### 
I J## 
I V## 
I J# 
I v#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on your flavor

```
I(J|V)[0-9]{1,3}
```

Do you also need a space after an "I"?

```
I (J|V)[0-9]{1,3}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your description does not match your example, and there are some idiomatic things that you'll need to take care of (case insensitivity, that depends on the regex engine)

```
I [JV]\d{1,3}
```

This will match

- I J1
- I J12
- I J123
- I V1
- I V12
- I V123

But WILL NOT MATCH

- I 1
- I 12
- I 123

Answer (score 1):

Tested with RegExBuddy:

I [JV]\d{1,3}\s

Edited:

Pretty much like Vinko Vrsalovic one, but with his, if you have I J12345678, It will grab "I J123" in your expression. Adding \s demands a special char at the end, like a space, line feed, etc...

Comment: Yes. But that depends on how will it be used. For example it might be better to end it with $ instead of \s, or just leave it without it.

Comment: You're right. But according to his example, the data is is one single line. So, using $ will only work if there's one I J123 value in the string...

Answer (score 0):

I think the others missed the `v#` spec.

```
I[JVv]\d{1,3}
```

Of course perhaps the lowercase `v` was a typo.